# In angularjs, why does the value of ng-model remain the same in a select?

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple form where a user can select a language and press Save. The initial value of the `<select>` is the users language on the web page.

I have the following JS code in my controller:

```
$scope.usersLanguage = loadUsersLanguage(); // e.g. "en"
$scope.allLanguages = loadAllLanguages(); // array of all languages
$scope.interviewLanguage = $scope.usersLanguage; // preselecting the drodown

$scope.logThis() = function() {
    console.log($scope.interviewLanguage); // Always prints "en"
}
```

and the following HTML

```
<select
    ng-model="interviewLanguage"
    ng-change="logThis()"
    ng-options="language.Id as language.Name for language in allLanguages"
></select>
```

The `ng-change` is just for logging purposes.

My problem is that regardless of what I change the language dropdown to, it always prints the initial value. Never changes. And I've double checked the array `allLanguages`, they all have unique ids and names.

Any ideas? Previous similiar StackOverflow-questions were no help.

Comment: code you posted works http://plnkr.co/edit/FdYfpCJtID1DAEPDu4xX?p=preview

Comment: Weird. Then something in the rest of my code messes it up. Have no idea why.

Comment: clear the cache and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found what was wrong. What's not shown in my HTML above is that my entire HTML is wrapped around a `<div ng-if="condition">`.

Then in certain states, the DOM would be removed and bindings broke.

Changing `ng-if` to `ng-show` solved the problem since the latter only hides/shows the DOM, instead of destroying it.

Answer (score 0):

It could also be a reference problem. 
Try using `$scope.interviewLanguage = angular.copy($scope.usersLanguage);`